# Vue: Access Vue instance from function outside instance scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is a small portion of my data object. Basically, it's used to create a navigation menu. Inside that navigation menu there are certain buttons that should trigger functions, and I figured I'd create the functions inside the data object because it's the clearest way to make it.

However, `this` does not return a vue object. So apart from making the vm part of the global scope I'm at a loss for how I would do this.

Any ideas?

```
const data = {
  login: {
    title: "Log in",
    icon: "fa fa-sign-in",
    action: function () {
      console.log("Log in");
      // This is where I want to access the vm, e.g. like this:
      // this.$root.showLoginBox();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Within your vue instance call `data.login.action.bind(this)()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like bad practice to define functions that a Vue instance will use outside of that instance's scope.

But, if you really need to keep your `data` object where it is, you can bind `this` to the function from within the Vue instance:

```
const data = {
  login: {
    action: function () {
      console.log(this)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  created() {
    data.login.action.bind(this)();
  }
})
```

[Here's a working codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmJWrg?editors=0010)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! :D Just had to make a minor alteration, the bind function actually returns a new version of the function, so what I wanted was actually data.login.action = data.login.action.bind(this), but I wouldn't have gotten there without your help, so thank you :)